# How can I travel to ICE or DHS headquarters?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, legal, government-buildings

Ok, so for our social studies project, I need to have a 'cultural experience' related to the group of people we are studying. This works well for someone who actually is studying 'Africa' or 'Southeast Asia', but unfourtunately we are studying the Department of Homeland Security, so **is there any way for us to travel to ICE headquarters or DHS headquarters, because there is no 'visit us' link on the website?**

Comment: I would think that, for security reasons, their headquarters are not visible.  You may need to contact them to see what sort of an interaction that might be acceptable, but it seems that meeting Americans involved with immigration and border security would not be a cultural experience *per se*, assuming you are, yourself, in the U.S.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie The headquarters are visible, like every US government department.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Department_of_Homeland_Security#Headquarters.  Also your assertion about cultural experience is puzzling.  Everything is a cultural experience if you look at it as such.

Comment: You could visit the outside of the buildings, but that's really as far as you're going to get unless you have a relationship with someone who works inside. Maybe you could have the "cultural experience" of meeting with people who have had interactions with DHS or ICE to learn about their experiences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to travel except for the nature of the agencies involved here.

Comment: @phoog I assume that Jim means visitable rather than visible.

Comment: Of course there's a way to travel there. How do you think their employees get there? Once you've found out where they are, you get there by all the usual methods.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm sure the NSA is working on that one.

Comment: @o.m. so you are suggesting using the blatantly off-topic tag? I'll need to travel 3 hours to the nearest field office, so I think this is on topic at travel.SE. If not, where is it on topic?

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder, there does not have to be a SE board where this is on topic. We're talking about airlines, trains, visa, quite a lot of things, but visiting hours of government offices are not usually covered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try contacting either the ICE or the DHS public affairs officials.

For example, for the [DHS](https://www.dhs.gov/office-public-affairs) :

" **The Office of Public Affairs is the primary point of contact for news media, organizations and the general public seeking information** about Department of Homeland Security's programs, policies, procedures, statistics, and services. The Office assists the Secretary on all public affairs, as well as strategic and internal communications matters."

State your case, tell them that for your school project you'd like to visit them and ask them some questions. Most US department will gladly accept to that as an outreach program.

Be forthcoming, tell them your name, school, if possible your teacher name or your school principal name so they can check that your request is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Most offices dealing with national security or intelligence are closed to the public, and you are only admitted if you have an appointment with someone who works there and undergo a level of screening appropriate to the facility you are visiting. You may not make it past the front lobby, and in some cases past the front gate.

That said, government offices, like private ones, are workplaces, and if even members of the public could enter the office buildings unhindered, I am not exactly sure what you would get out of the trip. Consider that "headquarters" is not necessarily where the most representative or most important work takes place, especially for an agency like ICE where most activity is at field locations and administered from field offices. Most of the Pentagon, and CIA headquarters, and so on is filled with cubicles and conference rooms no different from any corporate office or academic administration building.

That said, education of the public regarding an agency's mission is a legitimate interest in the eyes of most offices, or at least in the eyes of their public affairs officers. Some, like NASA or the Drug Enforcement Agency or the Department of Agriculture, have museums or visitors centers specifically devoted to that purpose. In other cases, tours can be arranged for groups of visitors if requested in advance, as for the Pentagon.

My recommendation therefore would be to contact the appropriate public affairs office to see how they might accommodate someone doing research for a school project. Agency contact information is [linked from the DHS website](https://www.dhs.gov/component-agency-contacts). If you know someone who works for one of the offices within DHS, you can also inquire with them about rules regarding visitors. It's possible that there are low-security offices where you would be able to visit a friend, but you might still require screening beforehand.

Comment: Back in the 1990's, it was possible to just walk into the Pentagon. There was a small area that anyone could access (they had a cafe IIRC), and there was a desk there where you could sign up to go on a guided tour the same day, which required you to pass through an airport-security like checkpoint. Unfortunately, some people ruined it for the rest of us in 2001 and you aren't allowed to do that anymore.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Indeed, I remember the post-Oklahoma City debates about restricting access to the Capitol, which is supposed to be "the people's house," with bipartisan opposition to centralized screening. It was even part of the Republican platform to re-open Pennsylvania Avenue in front of the White House. Now, you can't even walk down Pennsylvania Avenue next to the White House, where tourists liked to take pictures; they keep you on the sidewalk on the opposite side of the street.